# Journey is not firing

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder

We have a simple journey and we want it fires inmediatly when a customer submits a smart capture.

We had done everything documentation and forums says but it doesn't start by itself.

- http://help.exacttarget.com/en/documentation/journey_builder/how_to_fire_an_event/
- [Firing Events in Journey Builder](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/60409/firing-events-in-journey-builder)
- [Journey Builder is not starting](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/44427/journey-builder-is-not-starting)

The only way to start it is by running manually an automation with a fire event when data is recorded in data extension, but we can't have this manual operation.

1. We have a data extension: FistName, Cellphone, Email (As subscriber key)
2. Data extension is created as Population (1:1) in Contact Builder and Email field is linked with Contact Key.
3. Data extension is Set as Root and Email field is added in Channel Address Order.
4. We have a Entry Event associated to this Data extension (we have tried with Contact Data Entry Event and CloudPages Form Submit Entry Event because it's suppose these are Real Time entry events).
5. We had tried setting in Journey and Entry Events "Email is not null"  as filter criteria; also not filtering with any criteria.
6. Doing all this journey is not firing when customer submit form. So we had to create an automation with a Fire Event. Still it is not working, except when we run this automation manually.

What else can we do to fire this journey without manual operation and without API?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are correct that a CloudPage Form Submit Event is real-time. Is your SmartCapture form on a CloudPage? If so this should work, but you will need to ensure that your SmartCapture Data DE is sendable.

However, if you need to use a Contact Data Event, then the only way to fire the Event (without using an Automation or the API) would be to set the Entry Schedule (in the Event) as indicated in the screenshot below. The minimum cadence is one hour.

[image: Entry Schedule]